# Move image javafx with arrows

Tags: java, javafx, graphic

The moving is not working it only moves 1 time. And when I move image then there are 2 images there. How to do this?

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
Image img1 = new Image( "com/resources/aqua.jpg" );
        gc.drawImage( img1, 0, 0, 50, 50 );
        theScene.setOnKeyPressed((event) -> {

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT ){

                gc.drawImage( img1, 50, 0, 50, 50 );

            }
        });
```

Comment: Have X and Y value of the Image as Variables. Then Increment them when you keypress.  gc.drawImage(img1, X, Y, SizeW, SizeH); Then, on KeyPress, X+= 50;

Comment: For this kind of functionality, I would strongly recommend using an `ImageView` and placing it in a `Pane` or `Group`, and then modify its `layoutX` property. `Canvas` is unlikely to be a good way to implement the kind of functionality you are looking at here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Canvas` isn't cleared if you draw a new image. You have to do this "manually" using [`clearRect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#clearRect-double-double-double-double-), e.g.:

```
private double minX;
private double minY;
private double width;
private double height;
private GraphicsContext gc;
private Image img1;

private void drawImage() {
    gc.drawImage(img1, minX, minY, width, height);
}

private void moveImage() {
    gc.clearRect(minX, minY, width, height);
    minX += 50;
    drawImage();
}

...

    this.gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    this.img1 = ...;
    this.minX = 0;
    this.minY = 0;
    this.width = 50;
    this.height = 50;
    this.drawImage();
    theScene.setOnKeyPressed((event) -> {

        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
            moveImage();
        }
    });
```

Comment: it says java null pointer exception when I try to open the screen on drawImage()

Comment: @manuel_k: most likely you have declared a local variable with the name `gc`, which hides the field. I added a few `this.` which should solve this problem (I guess).